# Networking in Swift Using WikipediaKit / Delegate Design Pattern

Tags: ios, swift, networking, delegates, wikipedia-api

I'm trying to request basic info from Wikipedia - user selects tableView row and is taken to a new view that displays info associated with the row (album descriptions). Flow is:

1. tableView Cell passes user choice to network struct, performs segue to new view
2. network struct uses choice to query Wikipedia API
3. received info is passed via delegate method to new view
4. info is displayed in new view to user

Two issues I'm having:

1. Networking seems to not be carried out until after the new view is triggered and updated. Initially I didn't use delegate, and just had networking method return its result. But either way, I need networking to get its result back before we get to and update the new view. I've added Dispatch.main.async to the new view for the UI. I thought I may need a completion handler, but I don't fully understand this
2. Delegate protocol was introduced to fix problem 1, but it still doesn't work. For some reason nothing of the delegate method in the new view is triggering.

Here's the initial tableView trigger:

```
extension TopTenViewController: UITableViewDelegate {

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    
   albumManager.getAlbumInfo(albumTitle: topTenList[indexPath.row][1])
    
  performSegue(withIdentifier: "topTenAlbumInfoSeg", sender: self)
}
```

Here is the delegate and all the networking:

```
protocol AlbumManagerDelegate {

func didUpdateAlbumInfo(albumInfo: String)
}

struct AlbumManager {

var newResult: String = ""

var delegate: AlbumManagerDelegate?

func getAlbumInfo(albumTitle: String) {
    
    let wikipedia = Wikipedia.shared
    let language = WikipediaLanguage("en")
    
    let _ = wikipedia.requestArticle(language: language, title: albumTitle, imageWidth: 5) { result in
        
        switch result {
            
        case .success(let article):
            print(article.displayTitle)
            
            self.delegate?.didUpdateAlbumInfo(albumInfo: article.displayTitle)
            print("delegate should be updated")
        case .failure(let error):
            print(error)
            
        }
    }
}
```

}

Here is the target view:

```
class AlbumInfoViewController: UIViewController, AlbumManagerDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var albumDescriptionLabel: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var myWebView: WKWebView!

var albumDescription: String = ""
var albumManager = AlbumManager()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    albumManager.delegate = self
    print(albumDescriptionLabel.text)

}

func didUpdateAlbumInfo(albumInfo: String) {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        print("This worked: \(albumInfo)")
        self.albumDescriptionLabel.text = "Hi this is: \(albumInfo)"
    }
}

}
```

Currently nothing in didUpdateAlbumInfo in the new view is being triggered. albumDescriptionLabel is not being updated. Could the issue be that the segue is performed too soon? Thanks in advance!

Comment: In the target view you have a different instance of `AlbumManager` than the one in which you called `getAlbumInfo`, and you don't show setting the `delegate` property on any `AlbumManager` instance.  Start by implementing `prepareFor(segue:sender:)` so that you can set a property on the new view controller. This could be your existing album manager or the album for which you want data. I would suggest the latter.  Then, in `viewDidLoad` of the target, the target VC can set itself as the delegate and call `getAlbumInfo`.

Comment: Delegation probably isn't the best pattern here, however.  It would be better for the target VC to pass a completion handler to `getAlbumInfo`

Comment: Seems to have solved it! I called getAlbuminfo in the target VC instead - totally missed the different instances of AlbumManager. Thanks a lot for the suggestion.